# Result of Triple DES encryption in .Net and Java are different

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, encryption

I am trying to encrypt string in Java and .Net. But problem is that both algorithm produce different result. I am using Triple DES encryption algorithm.
It is supposed to produce same result.

My .Net Method:

```vb
Public Function EncryptTripleDES(ByVal sIn As String, ByVal sKey As String) As String
    Dim DES As New System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
    Dim hashMD5 As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    ' scramble the key
            ' Compute the MD5 hash.
    DES.Key = hashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey))
    ' Set the cipher mode.
    DES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
    ' Create the encryptor.
    Dim DESEncrypt As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor()
    ' Get a byte array of the string.
    Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sIn)
    ' Transform and return the string.
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
End Function
```

My Java class:

```
public class TrippleDESEncryption {
   private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
   public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede";
   private KeySpec keySpec;
   private SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory;
   private Cipher cipher;
   byte[] keyAsBytes;
   private String encryptionKey;
   private String encryptionScheme;
   SecretKey key;

   public TrippleDESEncryption() throws Exception {
          encryptionKey = "234342343423434234342343";
          encryptionScheme = DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
          keyAsBytes = encryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
          keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
          secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptionScheme);
          cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionScheme);
          key = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);

   }

   /**
   * Method To Encrypt The String
   */
   public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
          String encryptedString = null;
          try {
                 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                 byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
                 byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
                 BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
                 encryptedString = base64encoder.encode(encryptedText);
          } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return encryptedString;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have posted a java class versus a C# method so we can't tell you are passing the right parameters to the C# method.  You are using ASCII in C# and UTF-8 from Java for getting the key bytes which looks wrong.  I would start by checking the results of those GetBytes calls against each other.

Comment: **Don't use Triple DES nowadays.** It only provides at best 112 bit of security even if you use the largest key size of 192 bit. If a shorter key size is used, then it only provides 56 or 57 bits of security. AES would be faster (processors have a special AES-NI instruction set) and even more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with 3DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("DESede");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Everyone for you support. I find solution, here is my solution. This VB.NET method working fine.My only mistake was that my VB.NET method was  using ANSIEncoding and Java Class was using UTF8 .

```
 Public Function DecryptTripleDES(ByVal sOut As String, ByVal sKey As String) As String
    Try
        Dim DES As New System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        DES.Key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sKey)
        ' Set the cipher mode.
        DES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        ' Create the decryptor.
        Dim DESDecrypt As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor()
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(sOut)
        ' Transform and return the string.
        Return System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DESDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: OK iff you are only interested in encryption and not security. If you need security not use 3DES because it is not secure, use AES, do not use ECB mode because it is not secure, use CBC with a random iv. See the comments by Artjom B. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: Thanks a lot @zaph for your valuable comment. In future I will take care of it. My problem was that encryption logic was decided by my client(Java)  and I had to write its equivalent decryption logic.

Comment: Just another case of bad security for bad reasons, obviously we are not professionals.